# Remove "Search Results: '%s'" and blank space from Woocommerce Shop Search Results Page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I am trying to remove the "Search results: ' ' " text that shows above products on the Woocommerce Storefront search results page. Below is an image with the referenced text circled:

[image]

I have tried looking under search.php in the theme editor, but could only find how to remove the "Search results for '%s'" from the breadcrumb. How would I remove only what is circled in the image above?

Edit:

I have used the following code to remove the search results title, but a blank space is left where the title was removed. How would I also remove this blank space?

```php
function filter_woocommerce_page_title($page_title){
  if (is_search()){
    {$page_title = '';
  }
}

add_filter('woocommerce_page_title', 'filter_woocommerce_page_title', 10, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `woocommerce_page_title` hook. If `is_search()` is true then you remove the text:

```php
do_action( 'woocommerce_page_title',
    function( $page_title ) {
        if ( is_search() ) {
            $page_title = ''; // Or your custom text
        }
        return $page_title;
    },
    10, 1
);
```

See the [Hooks Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html) for more info.

For hiding the margin that will remain, try setting the following CSS:

```css
.search .woocommerce-products-header__title {display: none;}
```

Comment: This code was not working for me, but I tried something that worked and added it to the question above. Do you know how I could also remove the blank space left behind when removing the title using that code?

Comment: The blank space is related to the margin. You could use a CSS trick to hide empty elements: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/e/empty/

Comment: When I add div:empty {display: none;} to the custom CSS, nothing appears to change. Is there something else that must be added to the CSS to remove the blank space for only the shop search results search results title?

Comment: Try filtering by the class: `.search .woocommerce-products-header__title`

Comment: @tinyiguanas I've update my answer. Can you check if that solves your problem?

Comment: Yes, that works great. I also added `.storefront-sorting {margin-top: -75px}` and `.search .storefront-breadcrumb {margin-bottom: -100px;}` to reduce blank space between products and the header.